# Print which rewrite rules were triggered before the request errored out

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

**Problem:** I need to know which Apache rewrite rules are being triggered, and possibly how.

**Context:** I'm trying to get a .xml request to rewrite to a .php script, all I'm getting is a useless message (`[cgid:error] [pid 19515] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/www/xml/v3/availability.xml' failed` ). Apache version is 2.4.25.

**What I have tried:**

- add `LogLevel alert mod_rewrite.c:trace8` to the top of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and then `sudo systemctl restart apache2` - this achieved nothing, nothing extra shows up in the error log.
- I also tried putting it inside the `<Directory>` of the `<VirtualHost *:443>` entry (`sites-available & sites-enabled/test.conf`), this
  also yielded no results (while it does have `AllowOverride All`).
- I also tried `LogLevel debug`
- I also tried `rewrite:trace8` instead of `mod_rewrite.c:trace8`

Answer (score 0):

you can just put a hash symbol # in front of each rewrite rule which will prevent them from executing, then one by one remove the hash symbols # until you find which one is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The logs I were looking at were not the actual logs. There was a directive somewhere else setting the log location to another place. After finding the actual logs, I could see the debug information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).